# mom-husband-wife thing

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I heard this one on TV, too. Here is the quote:

> **Narrator:** Sara is isolated geographically and emotionally from her
>   family and friends.
>   **A friend:** Five years had gone by where **we were
>   doing the mom-husband-wife thing**. And she's on a yacht swimming in the
>   ocean.

I gave a lot of thought to what she might be meaning here but couldn't figure it out. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: The friend is referring to some archetypical lifestyle involving a mom, a husband, and a wife (it is not clear whether the mom and the wife are the same person), in which the friend was involved for five years with Sara. It is not clear what exactly that entails, especially without additional context.

Answer (score 3):

An expression such as this requires context. It is probable that the relationship has already been described in the story and this is a brief way of referring back to it.

Comment: OK, I think I've figured out something, I'm flagging it to be closed. Thank you :)